# Meteor $push adds object - need just one string value

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I need to add just the string to the array, here's my code:

```
Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$push: {follow:{memberId}}});
```

But it creates an object in the database, like this:

```
"follow" : [ 
    {
        "memberId" : "Yuzy5hHskjHwRu3TS"
    }
]
```

What I need is like this:

```
"follow":["Yuzy5hHskjHwRu3TS"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried `$addToSet` with the same result.

Comment: Possible reason is the curly braces around memberId. If you remove those, then you would see the expected result. db.welcome.update({_id:5}, { $push: {"follow" : "123" } } ) worked fine

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Why don't you create an answer and I accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have surrounded the variable inside curly braces, mongo thinks that you wanted to insert an array of documents. 
In your case, the correct way to insert element is

```
db.collection.update({_id:5} , {$push : { "follow" : "123" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Barney says, you just have an extra set of curly braces:

```
Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$push: {follow: memberId }});
```